Is there a 'directionality' to what geometry can solve?
Once again, I have stumbled into a question where I don't even really know what terminology describes it (heck, I don't even know what field of math it belongs to), so bear with me.
A friend gave me a geometry problem that boiled down to the following image:

Distances $l$, $d$, and $\rho$ as well as angle $\alpha$ are all known; line $OT$ bisects $\angle PTQ$. The goal is to find angle $\psi$.
By dropping perpendiculars from points $P$ and $Q$ to line $OT$ and using the resulting similar triangles, I got the equation
$$l\sin(\alpha-\psi)\left(d\cos\psi-\rho\right)=d\sin\psi\left(l\cos(\alpha-\psi)-\rho\right)$$
which, upon expanding and recombining terms, becomes
$$\cos\alpha\left(\sin2\psi-\frac{\rho}{d}\sin\psi\right)-\sin\alpha\left(\cos2\psi-\frac{\rho}{d}\cos\psi\right)=\frac{\rho}{l}\sin\psi$$
This equation confirmed my initial fears about the problem: it would be a lot easier if $\psi$ was known and $\alpha$ was the goal instead of the other way around. Because if that were the case, the equation above is essentially of the form $a\cos\alpha+b\sin\alpha=c$ which isn't very hard to solve, but with the given problem... well, I've left my approximate solution in a comment below.
My question isn't solving my friend's problem (though that would be nice). I'm more curious about this 'directionality': the fact that, for the same setup, you can get from one set of knowns to an unknown, but you can't get from another set of knowns to a different unknown. I've not rigorously gone through all the combinations, but glancing at the equations, it seems like the only unsolvable case is where $\psi$ is the unknown; set any other constant as the unknown and it can be isolated. What within the tools of geometric problem-solving would take a setup with clearly enough constraints so as to have a single solution from being trivially easy to seemingly impossible just by changing the target output?

Link to desmos graph with my solution included:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h9qfawo2mx

"What within the tools of geometric problem-solving would take a setup with clearly enough constraints so as to have a single solution from being trivially easy to seemingly impossible just by changing the target output?" You could, for example, have a problem that comes down to a general sixth-degree equation, which is "impossible" to solve if by "solve" you mean write the solution in radicals, but a numeric solution is still simple enough to find. In the example given above, it turns out to be fairly straightforward to find $\psi$; it's just a matter of finding the "trick" to do so.

This isn't really about geometry, it's algebra.
Suppose $a \sin(2 \psi) + b \cos(2 \psi) + c \sin(\psi) + d \cos(\psi) = 0$.  Using the double angle formulas, this says that $2 a x y + b (2 x^2 - 1) + c y + d x = 0$ where $x = \cos(\psi)$ and $y = \sin(\psi)$.  Using $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, we can eliminate $y$ to get a quartic equation for $x$:
$$ \left(4 a^{2}+4 b^{2}\right) x^{4}+\left(4 a c +4 b d \right) x^{3}+\left(-4 a^{2}-4 b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right) x^{2}+\left(-4 a c -2 b d \right) x +b^{2}-c^{2} = 0$$
Quartics can be solved using radicals, but the formulas are messy.

This does not answer the question. OP's question was not about solving the problem presented.

[+1] I totaly disagree with the previous comment. Your answer brings a lot to this question.

@JeanMarie I can see how this answer can potentially bring a lot to this question if it were more explicit, but as it is currently written I have to agree with Nicholas.

Two parts :



About the problem itself, as you have said it "would be nice" to solve it, here is how I would advise do. See figure below.



First of all, I am "not at ease" with these two triangles sticked in this way. I prefer to work on the following equivalent configuration where triangle $OQT$ is "folded" onto triangle $OPT$ (the resulting triangle being $OQ'T$). Please note that in this way, there is no longer need to invoke an angle bissector.
The "new" angles in $O$ are $\alpha-\psi$ and $2\psi-\alpha$ (check that their sum is $\psi$).
Let us now express that the sum of areas of triangles $OQ'T$ and $OPQ'$ is equal to the area of $OPT$ :
$$\tfrac12 \ell \rho \sin(\alpha-\psi)+ \tfrac12\ell d \sin(2 \psi-\alpha)=\tfrac12\rho d \sin \psi$$
Dividing by $\frac12  \ell \rho d$ :
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{d}\sin(\alpha-\psi)+ \frac{1}{\rho} \sin(2 \psi-\alpha)-\frac{1}{\ell}  \sin \psi}_{f(\psi)}=0\tag{1}$$
which is equivalent to your equation with the constraint $\psi \in (0,\pi)$.
Therefore, the issue is to find the roots of equation $f(\psi)=0$.
At this stage, I would plot, knowing the numerical values of $\ell, \rho, d, \alpha$, the graphical representation of function $f$ in order to see if there exist a solution (and hopefuly more than one solution). Then, and only then, I would expand the expression of $f$ (as done for example by @Robert Israel). I will not do it, but it is evident that there are values of $\ell, \rho, d, \alpha$ yielding no solutions for $\psi$.

(geogebra contruction downlable here)



(EDIT) Some thoughts about what you call the "directionality".



If we consider again the given example, trying to think in more general terms, let us re-write equation (1) (the example we have at hand) under the form :
$$F(\ell, \rho,d,\alpha,\psi)=0\tag{2}$$
with $5$ "letters".
It is not necessarily $\psi$ which is the unknown, the other being given parameters.
You ask for a general issue, i.e., with an algorithmic "flavor".
I think there is no general answer.
Let us consider for example the case where $\ell$ would be the unknown, with $ \rho,d,\alpha,\psi$ known parameters ; the value of $\ell$ will be obtained, either by (easily) solving equation (1), or, in a more or less equivalent manner, by constructing line segment $OQ'$.
Therefore, your question looks (to my eyes) to deal with the large, ancient, complex and interesting field of constructibility.
Final remark (that I will not deepen) : I met this issue of "directionality" while working with "Prolog" language (it is why I mentionned the algorithmic nature) with sometimes paradoxical "behaviors". Have you ever seen this language ?

This does not answer the question. OP's question was not about solving the problem presented.

@Nicholas Todoroff Downvoting should be kept for extreme cases. Even if I think your own answer doesn't answer the issue, I don't downvote it...

Downvoting is not for "extreme cases", it is a normal part of using this site. It's not an attack on you, it's a number displayed on a webpage that is now a smaller number. An answer that ignores or even misunderstands the question asked deserves to be downvoted.

@DavidK That is ignoring the question. OP understands quite well that the problem has a solution, and even presented their own solution (albeit in a Desmos link). They are asking "why are some (geometric) quantities more difficult to solve for than others?" The fact that a solution exists is irrelevant, as is the particular problem presented.

@NicholasTodoroff Yes, that's somewhat more obvious if you follow the link, which I can see now that I've done that. (In my defense, OP did label finding $\psi$ as "unsolvable", and I took that perhaps too literally.)

@DavidK Ah, I see how that's confusing now. I think what they were trying to say by "unsolvable" was "cannot easily put in the form $\psi =\cdots$", as their last sentence is "...from being trivially easy to seemingly impossible just by changing the target output..." (emphasis mine).

@Nicholas Todoroff For example, in my equivalent problem, I have got rid of the line bissector constraint : isn't it in the spirit of identifying the "true" variables on which this issue is based ? But not only for this issue : it is an idea that can be used in other contexts...

@JeanMarie I don't know what to say to you other than to quote OP (emphasis mine): "My question isn't solving my friend's problem. I'm more curious about this 'directionality'... What within the tools of geometric problem-solving would take a setup with... a single solution from being trivially easy to seemingly impossible just by changing the target output?" The particular problem is wholly irrelevant. OP is essentially asking given a geometric setup, why is it hard to solve for some variables in terms of the others, but at the same time solving for some variables is easy?

Telling OP that the problem they posited isn't actually that hard, is ignoring the question. We can replace the problem with any other problem which has the asymmetry that OP is asking about, and we can keep doing so until we find one that you can't say is easy. We could even completely remove any explicit geometric problem from OP's question, and the question would still stand and would deserve an answer. If your answer would not make sense (and I would claim it wouldn't) if OP were to remove his friend's geometry problem from the question, then you haven't answered their question.

@Sebastian Mostek See my edit.

I appreciate the edit, and think its enough to rescind my downvote.

I think it's a matter of what's in your tool box.
Expressing solutions to problems about right triangles is difficult if you don't allow yourself to use the symbols $\sin$ and $\cos$. Imagine that, as an alternative, you end up deriving their power series and positing that as a solution to such a problem; then it would look quite complicated indeed.
Similarly, there is clearly a well defined (though perhaps partial or discretely multivalued) function $(l,d,\rho,\alpha)\mapsto\psi$; if you add this function to your toolbox, then of course the above problem is trivial, and it would greatly simplify the solution of similar problems.

I don't understand at all how your answer is connected to the question : in particular, where do you see right triangles ? What is the point to consider power series ? why should we think in terms of toolboxes, and end up   in this way in a "trivial problem" ?

@JeanMarie Please reread the question in its entirety.
